# Can an XSLT key be created on a set of string tokens?

Tags: php, key, xslt-1.0

I have a string that contains a set of file names eg;

```
"foo.jpg,bar.jpg"
```

which I'm passing to an XSL stylesheet;

```
<xsl:param name="images"/>
```

Can I create an XSLT key on those file names somehow?

I have tried this;

```
<xsl:variable name="tokens" select="str:tokenize($images, ',')"/>
<xsl:key name="mykey" match="$tokens/*" use="token"/>
```

but I get an error;

```
Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): compilation error: file
file:///C:/root/sites/bec/ line 105 element key
in C:\root\php\lib-2013-04-23.php on line 157
Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): xsl:key : XPath pattern
compilation failed '//$tokens/*'
```

I'm using XSLT 1.0 courtesy of PHP's libxml (version 2.7.3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You're using XSLT1.0 with EXSLT (http://www.exslt.org/), wich is defined in your stylesheet as `xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"`. The `<xsl:variable name="tokens" select="str:tokenize($images, ',')" />` line declares a variable wich holds `<token>foo.jpg</token><token>bar.jpg</token>` string. So now you can use this variable to select or compare against your source XML tag values/attributes.
2. You're misunderstood the meaning of `<xsl:key>` element. It declares a named key that can be used with the `key()` function. When you use this function like `<xsl:for-each select="key('name', 'value')" />`, it iterates through your **source XML nodes**, wich was declared by the `match` attribute of `<xsl:key>` element, and searches the value inside the specified `use` attribute. **It can not be used to search inside XSL variables**, and it completely useless.

Take a look at this example:

***test.xml***

```
<root>
  <img src="foo.jpg" width="128" height="128" alt="First ldpi image" />
  <img src="my.jpg" width="64" height="64" alt="My image" />
  <img src="foo.jpg" width="256" height="256" alt="First hdpi image" />
  <img src="your.jpg" width="64" height="64" alt="Your image" />
  <img src="bar.jpg" width="128" height="128" alt="Second image" />
</root>
```

***test.xsl***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
   xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:param name="images" />
  <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="str:tokenize($images, ',')"/>

  <xsl:key name="mykey" match="img" use="@src"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <by-key>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('mykey', 'my.jpg')" />
      </by-key>
      <by-node-set>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </by-node-set>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/root/img[@src]">
    <xsl:if test="exsl:node-set($tokens)/text() = @src">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

***test.php:***

```
<?php

$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$result = $xml->load('test.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$result = $xsl->load("test.xsl");

$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$xslt->setParameter('', 'images', 'foo.jpg,bar.jpg');
$xslt->importStylesheet($xsl);
file_put_contents('result.xml', $xslt->transformToXML($xml));

?>
```

***result.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings">
  <by-key>
    <img src="my.jpg" width="64" height="64" alt="My image"/>
  </by-key>
  <by-node-set>
    <img src="foo.jpg" width="128" height="128" alt="First ldpi image"/>
    <img src="foo.jpg" width="256" height="256" alt="First hdpi image"/>
    <img src="bar.jpg" width="128" height="128" alt="Second image"/>
  </by-node-set>
</root>
```